# minimizing total travel time

Tags: python, optimization, k-nearest-neighbour

[image]

Green circles are salesman and A-B-C are destination points. I need to move green circles so that total travelled time should be minimum and each salesman should go to a different point. So ideal solution is I wish to achive is:
1-c, 2-a, 3b

I want to learn "**name of this problem and suitable algorithms?**"

What I've tried so far:

First, I've tried brute force with loops trying out all different combinations but it takes too much time to calculate. (In real world I've around 50-60 salesman & points) and I need to find a result in ~10 seconds. I've written standard for-loops in Python, maybe I can increase speed by using numpy but I am not sure if it is possible and it doesn't sound like a clever solution

Second, I've tried nearest neighbour ([balltree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#kdtree-and-balltree-classes) to be specific) algorithms to find closest points to each salesman but in that case result is 1-c, 2-a, 3-a so B stays empty.

Finally, for each point I've calculated closest n points and sorted them according to minimum distance and in that case result is 1-c, 3-a, 2-b. This one minimize total distance but I am interested in decreasing total travel time not total distance. In other words, I want to minimize maximum distance a salesman travelled.

Best,

Answer (score 3):

This is the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) in [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), usually taught as part of operations research.

Between the links and the keywords to search for, this should get you started.